# Ac Fan motor capacitor value

Tags: capacitor, motor, ac, capacitance, fan

I have a bad 350v 2 uf fan capacitor. I managed to find a 400v 6.3uf cap in my locality, would this work instead of the 2uf one?

Thanks.[image]

Comment: Not recommended. Buy one with the correct capacitance.

Comment: It might work, but you should be able to find one that is closer than that, but remember what I said re start capacitors vs run capacitors in response to your first question about this.

Comment: I added an image, maybe you could tell me the type of capacitor? Im not sure what type it is.

Comment: It doesnt look like a typical electrolytic however.

Comment: Have you tried to see if the manufacturer has data on their website? That would tell you what type it is. But gets you no closer to finding one with the correct value.